# Webdriver: wait until staleness not working only on Safari

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, automated-tests

There's a simple scene that needs to wait until a spinner disappear from the DOM, so my code is:

```
driver.findElements(By.id('plain-spinner'))
    .then((eles) => {
      if (eles.length > 0) return driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(eles[0]), 12000, 'Spinner cannot disappear');
});
```

The above code works well for every browser but Safari. In safari, it just wait until timeout and print 'Spinner cannot disappear', like nothing has happened.

Versions: OS is mac 10.12 and selenium-webdriver is 3.4, safari is 11.01.

Comment: You could try implicit wait as well..

Comment: I've been having this problem as well. I ended up checking that that the length of the `findElements` function was zero.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to address your issue by a different approach as follows:

If the `WebPage` you are dealing with have a `spinner` probhably the application is `AngularJS` based. So instead of using the `ExpectedConditions` clause as **`stalenessOf`** for the spinner element, I will use some other clause, one among the following :

- Once the spinner have disappeared, if you are trying to click on any `WebElement` next use **`elementToBeClickable((By.id("next_element"))`**
- Once the spinner have disappeared, if you are trying to verify presence of any `WebElement` use **`presenceOfElementLocated((By.id("next_element"))`**